# Finding the shortest substring containing keywords

Tags: java, strings, clustering

> **Problem:** Write a function that takes a `String document` and a `String[] keywords` and returns the smallest substring of `document` that contains all of the strings in `keywords`.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - `document` will contain at least 1 word
> - `document` will separate words by a single space
> - A word can only contain `[a-z]` and can appear multiple times in the document
> - `keywords` will be a distinct list of words
> - Matches must be perfect (ie `bat` and `batman` do not match)
> - If there are multiple shortest substrings, pick the first one
> - keywords can appear in the substring in any order
> - The substring length is counted in words, not characters
> - Must be written in Java 7 and provide a class called `Solution` with a method `solution`
>
> **Examples**
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> document: "a b c d a"
> keywords: ["a", "c", "d"]
> ```
>
> Output: `"c d a"`
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> document: "world there hello hello where world"
> keywords: ["hello", "world"]
> ```
>
> Output: `"world there hello"`

**My attempt:**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

//Time Complexity: O(w + ws)
//Space Complexity: O(s)
//Where w is the number of words in the document, and s is the number of search terms
public class Solution {
    private Map<String, Integer> snippetDataPoints = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private String[] words, searchTerms;
    private int shortestSnippetStart = 0, shortestSnippetEnd, currentSnippetStart = 0;

    public static String solution(String document, String[] searchTerms) {
        Solution solution = new Solution (document.split(" "), searchTerms);//document.split isnt the most efficient, but we are already over O(n), and this keeps it simple
        return solution.solve();
    }

    private Solution(String[] words, String[] searchTerms){
        this.words = words;
        this.searchTerms = searchTerms;
        shortestSnippetEnd=words.length;
    }

    private String solve(){
        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            if(searchTermsContains(words[i])){
                addToSnippet(words[i], i);
            }
        }
        StringBuilder snippet = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = shortestSnippetStart; i<=shortestSnippetEnd; i++){
            snippet.append(words[i] + " ");
        }
        snippet.deleteCharAt(snippet.length()-1);
        return snippet.toString();
    }

    private void addToSnippet(String word, int position) {
        Integer previousPosition = snippetDataPoints.put(word, position);
        if(previousPosition == null || previousPosition <= currentSnippetStart){
            currentSnippetStart = Collections.min(snippetDataPoints.values());
        }
        if(snippetDataPoints.size() == searchTerms.length){
            determineShortestSnippet(position);
        }
    }

    private void determineShortestSnippet(int currentPositionEnd) { 
        if(shortestSnippetEnd - shortestSnippetStart > currentPositionEnd - currentSnippetStart ){
            shortestSnippetStart = currentSnippetStart;
            shortestSnippetEnd = currentPositionEnd;
        }
    }

    private boolean searchTermsContains(String word) {
        for(String searchTerm : searchTerms){
            if(searchTerm.equals(word)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**My Analysis:**
This was written with a time constraint, so it manages to keep simplicity without losing too much efficiency. The `document.split()` is unnecessary - I could have done the parsing on the fly, but it would have been more complicated. Similarly, I could have created a better implementation of `searchTermsContains`, perhaps using a tree of character nodes to minimize search time. However, it would be *really* great if I could significantly reduce the usage of `searchTermsContains` altogether since its adding a `ws`to my time complexity, but I cant think of anyway.

I also could have used a more efficient data structure for the `snippetDataPoints`. I think a parallel array would have worked just as well and used significantly less memory (though still technically `O(s)`?). And finally, a lot of my code runs under the assumption that all input is perfectly valid - something Im willing to accept given time constraints and the nature of the problem.

Comment: Was this, by any chance, an [tag:interview-question], like [this one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48374/9357)?

Comment: @200_success not an interview question, but basically just a java variant of the problem

Answer (score 2):

**Problems / Bugs**

- The following calls will all throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

  ```
  String document = "a b c d";
  System.out.println(Solution.solution(document, new String[]{"g"}));
  System.out.println(Solution.solution(document, new String[]{"g", "a", "s", "s"}));
  System.out.println(Solution.solution(document, new String[]{"a", "b" ,"c", "d"}));
  ```

  because of

  > ```
  > for (int i = shortestSnippetStart; i <= shortestSnippetEnd; i++) {
  > ```

  **Assuming** you have fixed the above by changing to

  ```
  for (int i = shortestSnippetStart; i < shortestSnippetEnd; i++) {
  ```

  The above calls will return

  > a b c d
  >   a b c d
  >   a b c
- The following will throw an exception if `snippet.length==0`

  > ```
  > snippet.deleteCharAt(snippet.length()-1);
  > ```

**General**

- you shouldn't do string concatenation inside `StringBuilder.append()` method. The `append()` method returns a `StringBuilder`so you should just stack the calls like

  ```
  snippet.append(words[i])
         .append(" ");
  ```
- you shouldn't declare multiple variables in a single line, because this removes readability of the code.
- give your conditions/variables the possibility to breathe

  > ```
  > for(int i = shortestSnippetStart; i<=shortestSnippetEnd; i++){
  > ```

  should be

  ```
  for(int i = shortestSnippetStart; i <= shortestSnippetEnd; i++) {
  ```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear by adding it in the notes, but my last line about perfect inputs implies that all keywords will be in the doc, and keywords and doc have at least size 1